# : error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers; 'friend' is a keyword in Objective-C++ @property(

Tags: objective-c++

expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers; 'friend' is a keyword in Objective-C++
@property(nonatomic, readonly) LinphoneFriend *friend;

expected identifier; 'friend' is a keyword in Objective-C++
- (instancetype)initWithFriend:(LinphoneFriend *) friend;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please [edit] the question to include the code referenced by the error.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that `friend` is a keyword in C++:

> The friend declaration appears in a class body and grants a function or another class access to private and protected members of the class where the friend declaration appears.

via https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend

Unfortunately, your options are:

- rename your variables (eg to `linphoneFriend`)
- switch to Objective-C

Comment: @PashaMohamed Please edit your question to include the code that is causing the error and also what you tried and in what way that did not work. The answer provided is generally correct, so we will need more information to be able to help you.